# Pandas compute average for two consecutive rows and save result in two cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

**INPUT**

```
ID A
1  0.040
2  0.086
3  0.127
4  0.173
5  0.141
6  0.047
7  0.068
8  0.038
```

I want to create B column, each two row in B have the same average from A. As following:

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  A      B
1   0.040  0.063
2   0.086  0.063
3   0.127  0.150
4   0.173  0.150
5   0.141  0.094
6   0.047  0.094
7   0.068  0.053
8   0.038  0.053
```

I tried this code

```
df["B"]= (df['A'] + df['A'].shift(-1))/2
```

I got the average but I can't make it distrbute bi-row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [10]: df['B'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2)['A'].transform('mean')

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   ID      A      B
0   1  0.040  0.063
1   2  0.086  0.063
2   3  0.127  0.150
3   4  0.173  0.150
4   5  0.141  0.094
5   6  0.047  0.094
6   7  0.068  0.053
7   8  0.038  0.053
```